# How to pass options to MiniMagick while using Carrierwave's process?

Tags: ruby, carrierwave, minimagick

I have an uploader like this:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  version :titers_112x108 do
    process resize_to_fill: [112, 108, 'North']
  end
end
```

The problem is that I want to pass a `quality` parameter while resizing an image, so that my PNG image won't loose any quality in the process.

This option is [available](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) for ImageMagick's `mogrify` which is used in MiniMagick under the hood and [suggested](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-specify-the-image-quality#change-quality-with-minimagick) to use by Carrierwave as a separate process.

Looking into the [code](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/1.x-stable/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb#L213) of `CarrierWave::MiniMagick.resize_to_fill` we can see that we can pass options as the last argument to the method, so I tried doing this:

```
process resize_to_fill: [112, 108, 'North', { quality: '0' }]
```

but it fails with

```
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: quality 
  from .../gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb:191:in `resize_to_fill'
```

I'm using Carrierwave version `1.x`.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this ? Resized images lose a lot of quality.